# Risks to database and front-end coupling

Tags: servlets, web, frontend, backend, coupling

I could not come up with any better title, after reading the question you can suggest a better one. Also you can suggest some better tags, I could not find `web-development`.

I am a student so I don't know the standard way to achieve the following issue.

I usually set the IDs of elements (div,span,tr,etc) according to the database primary key to reference it later easily.

For example on page having some rows of entries having their id set to the sno in the DB which is primary key and on click on any row checking the id and display the result from database using that id.

But I think its a bad idea as anyone can use **Inspect Element** or **Dev Tools** and change the ID.

What is the standard way to achieve this?

**EDIT 1**
I know that `web browser wont enforce the security policy for me` that's why I am asking for the standard way, or standard practices to use for this matter.

Comment: Don't expect the web browser to enforce your security policy - the correct place to address those issues in your middleware or data layer.   Assume there are malicious users that are able to craft any HTTP request your server is able to respond to (there are, and they will).

Comment: That said, if you need deep integration between your document and and data elements, consider creating a data layer on the browser side and using ordinary javascript properties to map to the views.  Otherwise, using the document IDs is OK-ish.

Comment: @BadZen sorry but I dont know about `creating a data layer on the browser side` do you happen to know some blogs,wikis or any website where I can more learn about it ?

Comment: If you want a more specific topic for your title (as being generic isn't well received on SO), your post is about how close your database and front-end can be. Hence you could rename to "Risks to database and front-end coupling"

Comment: What @BadZen probably means by the *data layer on the browser side*, is to really maintain the data layer within the browser with some Javascript. Hence you could abstract the IDs from the HTML elements and move this over to Javascript. But even then, an attacker can move on to the Javascript as well.

Hence the best place to validate if the ID is correct and valid is in the back-end (middleware or data layer, as indicated by BadZen). If you have a web service which the front-end communicates with, you can validate it there and return an error response on unauthorized access to resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, you must assume that any request that comes to the back end may be forged, any any data sent to browser (visible or hidden) is *public*.

If you considere the the `id` are private (rather uncommon requirement), you could instead simply use a row order and keep on server session a table `row_order` <-> `id`.

If you simply want to ensure that the id are correct, just control them (server side) before updating the database, or at the time of the database write if you cannot control them before.

If you want to enforce any other policy (users have roles and depending on roles are allowed or not to update some values) all those controls have to be done server side.